# how to get user status (is online) on flutter web

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web

I am working on a flutter web project and want to get the status of the user (online?). I use WidgetsBindingObserver, but didChangeAppLifecycleState doesn't work on the web.

I tried this code.

```
  class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const HomePage({super.key});

    @override
    State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
  }
  
  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>with WidgetsBindingObserver {
    
    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state){
      if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
       //is online
      }else{
       //isn't
      }
    }
    @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
        if (kIsWeb) {
      window.addEventListener('focus', onFocus);
      window.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      window.removeEventListener('focus', onFocus);
      window.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur);
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
    void onFocus(Event e) {
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.resumed);
  }

  void onBlur(Event e) {
    didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState.paused);
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(body: Container(child:Text('hello') ));
    }
  }
```

When you focus and blur the web page, it works. The user is still online if you close the tab or browser. To no avail, I tried setting it to outline in the dispose method.

Comment: In flutter web you are always online. `AppLifecycleState` is applicable ony for mobile platforms.

Comment: but how can I get all the members on ligne?